# Mysqldump from same version of mysql results in The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Linux (CentOS7) vm I run mysqldump from:

mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Linux (CentOS7) vm I am importing the dump into:

mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

They look identical but when I try to import the dumped file I get:
ERROR 1214 (HY000) at line 1961: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

I understand that the fix is to change the InnoDB type to MyISAM but why do I need to do that?  Both versions are the same.  Did I miss something in creating the DB before I imported?  Misconfigured mysql?

Comment: I think you're looking at the version of the _client_. You need to look at the version of the _server_. Try `mysql -h $server -sse "select @@version"`

Comment: Don't change to MyISAM, that's a very brittle database engine not worth using, you'll lose transactions, journals, and performance, among other things. Update to a newer version of MySQL (e.g. 5.7) that supports it on InnoDB.

Comment: It looks like `FULLTEXT` on InnoDB has been supported since MySQL 5.6, so if you're on 5.5 you're missing out. 5.5 to 5.6 is pretty seamless, 5.6 to 5.7 has some issues if you're using aggregate functions ambiguously, so you need to be more careful.

Comment: Bill, you are correct.  Thanks for the solution